# How do I fix a degraded SharePoint 2013 index partition when there is only one of them?

Tags: 2013, search, index

We have a test environment that is no longer able to successfully crawl content.  The crawl logs show successful URLs, but I can't search for that content.  It has worked in the past, but stopped working for some unknown reason.

This is a single SharePoint 2013 server that is crawling SharePoint 2010 farms.  When looking at the search topology in the Search Service Application, I see:

[image]

I can also look at it with PowerShell and see that it is "degraded":

[image]

I tried resetting the index, but that did not help.  Looking at the ULS log, I see lots of errors.  Here are 3 examples:

> CSSFeedersManager::session_CallbackReceived: Document 55747 processing failed. Error messages: Failed to create session with indexer; Aborting insert of item in Link Database because it was not inserted to the Search Index.; , errorID = 2147749241  hostName = EATIFSPS2013A  nodeName = ContentProcessingComponent1
>
> Component and System=Content1-a9f229cd-e4ce-43b6-88c3-fab1cc9b6d45, Correlation ID=d57ff765-1ffc-4fc9-bb65-7e0f11e9abfb, Tenant ID=0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b Error code=800000, Flow Name=Microsoft.CrawlerFlow, Operator Name=InjectedOpForExceptionHandling/EventHybrid_Indexing, Message=The processing of item fails with error Failed to create session with indexer
>
> Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Processing.Mars.MarsWriterProducer: Failed to create session for index system: SPb0bb381ca970: Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Services.ContentRouter.ContentException: Unable to connect to index system SPb0bb381ca970
> at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.ContentRouter.ContentRouter.VerifyIndexSystem(String indexSystem)
> at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.ContentRouter.ContentRouter.OpenSession(String indexSystem, Action`1 callback, IDictionary`2 defaultPolicy)
> at Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Processing.Mars.MarsWriterProducer.GetSession(String indexSystem)

I have seen where I you have multiple index partitions you can remove one and add another.  If you only have one, I have read that you have to create a new search service application (as you cannot remove all index partitions).  Maybe I could add one and then remove the original/bad one.

I have also seen [on this blog](http://distefano.biz/blog/index.php/2013/02/07/sp-2013-activate-search-topology-fails/) where maybe I should open up TCP 808 ports inbound into my SharePoint 2010 sites (the content I am crawling).  We didn't close these on purpose, but maybe that did happen (I'm looking into it).

EDIT: I tried resetting the index and only crawling content on the single SharePoint 2013 machine and still have the problem. I don't think it has anything to do with firewall ports (TCP 808 or other).

Any recommendations?

Comment: I failed to update my answer, but I'm pretty sure I "solved" this by re-creating the SSA.  Not a good answer in most situations, and a little painful, but it worked for me.

Comment: my brand new search service application is getting created with degraded index partition,  any pointers.  I have already deleted it twice

Answer (score 12):

Index reset + full crawl of all content sources.

http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/08/sharepoint-search-index-partition-degraded.html

Comment: Index reset and full crawl is what did not work for me.

Comment: Index reset worked for me. My index partion was degraded because of a full disk.

Comment: worked for me too,  i was scared to delete and recreate the SSA again :)  thanks

Comment: looks like i am back again with same issue in a DEV envioronment,  i have already deleted and recreated my SSA,  but still coming up with degraded index component

Comment: This (luckily) worked for me as well. +1

Answer (score 12):

You don't have to rebuild the SSA, just create a new topology as shufler mentioned.  Here's a script that I just ran with my environment info, and it resolved the problem for me :)

```
#set Search Service Application
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

#recreate search topology with new index component
#reset the index if the bad component is the index

#grab component name of faulty topology component and it's respective server name
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus -SearchApplication $ssa -Text

#put server name where [SERVER] is.. remove the []
$hosta = get-spenterprisesearchserviceinstance -identity [SERVER]

#get the existing topology
$active = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Active

#copy the existing topology
$clone = New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Clone -SearchTopology $active

#remove the bad component, placing the name where [BAD COMPONENT NAME] is... remove the []
$ComponentID = (Get-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -SearchTopology $clone -Identity [BAD COMPONENT NAME]).componentID
Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -Identity $ComponentID.GUID -SearchTopology $clone -confirm:$false

#create the new component, the example below is for the index specifically - create a new folder for the index so it's empty!
New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $hostA -IndexPartition 0 -RootDirectory F:\SPIndex 

#Set this copy as the active topology
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -identity $clone
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'll look into this next time I have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can’t add a new index partition component when the existing one is failing:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/peter_dempsey/archive/2013/04/11/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-change-topology-when-generation-controller-is-not-active.aspx

So this is my steps to delete and create a new search service application with the excisting databases:

**Find database name**

Run powershell:

```
get-spdatabase | select name
```

And locate the name of your search database. For me, it is: SP_2013_EnterpriseSearch02

**Remove excisting search application**

- Go to central admin --> Application Management --> Manage Service Applications
- Mark your search searvice application and press delete.
- Leave "Delete data ..." UNTICKED (you don´t want to remove the database)

Or powerhshell:

```
$spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "<Service application display name>"
Remove-SPServiceApplication $spapp
```

If you cant delete it, try clean the cash
http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2013/10/12/clear-sharepoint-cache/

**Create new search application**

run following powershell

```
$applicationPool = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity 'SharePoint - Search'
$searchInst = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance –local
Restore-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name 'Search Service Application' -applicationpool $applicationPool -databasename 'SP_2013_EnterpriseSearch02' -databaseserver SQL01 -AdminSearchServiceInstance $searchInst
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy -Name 'Search Service Application Proxy' -SearchApplication $ssa
$ssap = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy 

Add-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroupMember –member $ssap -identity " "
```

**Reset index and start a crawl**

1. central admin --> manage service application --> search service --> Index Reset (left navigation under Crawling) --> reset Now
2. Still in Search Administration --> Content Sources --> on a content source drop down, click "Start full crawl".

Comment: I´ve added some more explanations.

Answer (score 1):

In a single server farm your options are really limited. The easiest method would be to recreate the Search SSA. I do this from a script and it should just take a few minutes on a decent machine.

I don't think (though I have not tried) removing and recreating the Index Component alone, but if killing the SSA is not an option you may want to try this first.

Comment: Alternatively to recreating the entire search service application you could try instead creating and activating a new topology with a new index component. This way you won't lose any of your search service configurations.

Comment: I just noticed this answer, Matt.  It has been awhile now, but I'm pretty sure I did, in fact, re-create the SSA.  I hesitate to say this is the correct answer because if faced with this situation again I may not have the luxury of re-creating the SSA.

Answer (score 0):

Check index partition status in SharePoint search application if it show error (yellow colour) then try this solution

https://mysolutioncafe.blogspot.in/#!/2016/11/sharepoint-2013-search-not-workingnot.html

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90873/sharepoint-2013-find-an-item-search-box-does-not-return-results/199811#199811). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!

Comment: especially if the link is likely to go down at some point.