# SharePoint 2013: "Find an Item" search box does not return results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list, search

We have 2 web applications,  in one of the web application search is working properly and we are able to see search results from "Find an Item" box above the list name.

However in the other web application, searching for contents in the site works file but when we try to "Find an Item" within a list,  it does not returns any results.

Even in the normal search we are not able to see List Items,  the search results return only documents within the site.

Is there a setting that drives this,  I have verified the list settings and it is set to show items in the search results and even re-indexed the list couple of times.

thanks

Comment: Have you checked in and published the items?

Comment: Hi Robert,  yes item was checked in and published.

Comment: I am onto another list,  the search box is able to search only first 20 items correctly.  Even though i can see the item in the list,  i am not able to search using "Find an Item" box.  any pointers?  Why is this so inconsistent.

Comment: I had a smiliar issue in a webpart-page with 2 list-views on the same list. The "Find an item"-function didn't return any results in the webpart. When I removed one of the list-view-webparts, the search did work fine. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As always,  all the strange issues have simple answer,  for on of the list where i was able to search 20 items, I noticed that we have "Content Approval" setting was turned on.

Hence all the items were considered as "Draft" and visible only to people with admin privileges.  Since i have full access on the farm I was able to see everything.

Another thing to keep in mind whenever you come across something similar...

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: I told you they where not published ;)

Comment: You were right Robert :)

Answer (score 5):

Look at your default Alternate access mappings.  Make sure that the crawl address is the same in the default text box as is the start crawl address in the search service application.  I had the same issue and changed my default address to be https:// site.company.com instead of http:// servername:port and the results populated immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Is it all lists in the site or just the one? Is it all site collections under the web application or only one?

If the whole site is the issue, Check Site Settings | Search and Offline Availability.
If the List only check List Settings | Advanced Settings | Search.

If all of that is correct, Ensure in the Search Service Application that the Web Application is included in the Content Source under SharePoint Start Addresses.

Then use the URL to the Site and List to check the Crawl Logs.

Answer (score -5):

Check index partition status in SharePoint search application if it show error (yellow colour) then try this solution

https://mysolutioncafe.blogspot.in/#!/2016/11/sharepoint-2013-search-not-workingnot.html

Comment: That link has nothing to do with SharePoint!