# Sharepoint 2013 Find list elements

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, search

We recently migrated our SharePoint installation from a testing/demo setup to our production server, and after much cursing and head scratching we more or less got it work like it used to on the testing server.

However, we noticed an odd problem - when displaying a list, using the search box that is displayed alongside the list items does not return any replies.
Using the search center, the lists - as a whole - shows up in the results.

For some list, the list search does work, but so far we have not been able to figure out what is the difference between those lists. 
It does not appear to be an approval or permission issue. When simply displaying the lists, all items are displayed, and using the global search center does return the lists in the results.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and managed to solve it? Google has not been very helpful in this case...
Thank you very much in advance for any light you might be able to shed on this issue!

Comment: did you check this one: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90873/sharepoint-2013-find-an-item-search-box-does-not-return-results

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! 
Yes, I did check it. The list was configured to require content approval, we already set it not to, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a problem like this and your using you own name as the search criteria, make sure you are not the account that is importing data or entering the data as it searches the modified by field and returns all items.  This makes you think that its not filtering results.  Duh I guess.