# Enterprise Search - Index Partition Consistently Degrading

Tags: enterprise-search, searchserviceapplication

I have a single server SharePoint 2013 farm, and use Enterprise Search.

The Index Partition keeps degrading.  I've seen one instance where it fixed itself, but on every other occasion, I have had to reset the index and reindex my sites.

Within hours (2 to 24) of me kicking off another full crawl, the index partition degrades again, and enterprise search breaks.

I have tried to delete and re-create the search service application.  Same problem occurs.

I read an article that suggested disk space could be a problem.  I can't see this as being a problem in my environment as every disk has a large chunk of space free.  Does anyone have guidance on how much free space I should have to not cause problems?

Where should I start troubleshooting this thing?

Comment: What do you mean by degrading? Are you talking about the time taken to crawl?

Comment: The index partition is showing as degraded.  When this happens, enterprise search falls over, users get "something went wrong".  here is an example of what is happening to me, but when I reset my index, or delete and recreate my search service application, the problem just reoccurs [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88697/how-do-i-fix-a-degraded-sharepoint-2013-index-partition-when-there-is-only-one-o)

Comment: Can you check the Health reports in Search and check where you find more latency?

Answer (score 1):

You can get more information about the degradation with this powershell:

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus -SearchApplication $ssa -Text
```

or more detailed for an index component with name IndexComponent1

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus -HealthReport -Component IndexComponent1 -Text
```

It could be a networking or storage problem. Relocating the index could be an option for the second problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info Max.  I ran those two commands, but the results haven't brought me much more clarity.  I tried to paste the results here, but my post was too long, so I have thrown them on pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/ycHwZ9ub)

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Strange - could be a hardware problem... hard to tell!